# how to relate to the price in pine editor

Tags: pine-script

i am very new on pine and coding in general. i am searching to test a strategy in which the price is crossing an SMA.
how do i describe the price?
can i use the "crossover" order like it is below?
i tried to search an answer in the guides of tradingView but it was pretty advanced for me. here is an example:

the **price** is what i am searching to describe

`longCondition = crossover( **price** , sma(close, 28))`

---

does anyone know a sours that teach pine editor for novice in coding like me?

thank you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your moving average into a variable, so you can use it whenever you want, then your crossover is correct, you can get the price with `close`, like this, when the candle will cross and will close above your MA, your condition is met.

You can use `high` instead of `close`, same principle, if the highest of the candle will cross the MA, your condition is met (this time will be triggered instantly, so will not wait for the candle to be closed).

To use shorts, you can use `crossunder()` function or just reverse `close` with `sma` (ex: `crossover(sma, close)`), but most of the time people use `crossover()` for longs and `crossunder()` for shorts.

```
sma = sma(close, 28)
longCondition = crossover(close, sma)
shortCondition = crossunder(close, sma)
```